# How do I resolve this pivot_table error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

The error description says almost nothing about the cause. What actually caused this error? What should I change to resolve this error?

**The command I ran in my Jupyter notebook:**

```
temp2 = df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status',index= 'Credit_History'],aggfunc=lambda x: x.map({'Y':1,'N':0}).mean())
```

**And the error displayed in console:**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-36df2773019b> in <module>()
----> 1 temp2 = df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status',index=['Credit_History'],aggfunc=lambda x: x.map({'Y':1,'N':0}).mean())

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot_table(self, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
   5298                            aggfunc=aggfunc, fill_value=fill_value,
   5299                            margins=margins, dropna=dropna,
-> 5300                            margins_name=margins_name)
   5301 
   5302     def stack(self, level=-1, dropna=True):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot_table(data, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
     57         for i in values:
     58             if i not in data:
---> 59                 raise KeyError(i)
     60 
     61         to_filter = []

KeyError: 'Loan_Status'
```

**Here is a sample of my dataframe: **

[image: df.sample()]

**Here is df.columns(): **

[image: df.columns()]

Comment: Please show us a sample of your dataframe. Also helpful would be `print(df.columns)`.

Comment: @jpp added outputs of df.sample() and df.columns().

Comment: Check your `df.columns`. There's no "Loan_Status". You can't have pivot values as a column which doesn't exist.

Comment: @jpp Thanks, I used the wrong .csv file. How did you find the error? It doesn't show a "variable not found error".

Comment: Pandas' version of "variable not found" is `KeyError: 'Loan_Status'`, which is the error you got.